# transparent package not working in LaTeX

Tags: errors, transparency, dvi-mode

I've been working on a document which involves the `transparent` package.  It compiles fine with pdfLaTeX, but when I try bare LaTeX (I want to get a DVI file) it generates an `Undefined control sequence` error.  Minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\transparent{0.5}{Hello}
\end{document}
```

I have a feeling this is nothing to do with the `transparent` package per se, and is perhaps just something needing updating.  But I don't know how to find out what's causing the problem, or how to fix it.  If it's relevant, I'm using MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: before the error you get a fairly clear message `Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.`  The package does not support dvi mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before the error you get a fairly clear message:

```
 Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted,
 because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.
```

The package does not support dvi mode.

The package uses uses several commands specific to the  pdf features of pdftex so making a variant of the package that worked with dvi mode might be non trivial (but no doubt possible, at least for some cases)